# Android Studio project could not synchronise with Gradle files

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a new app developer and, I am trying to build up the foundation of the knowledge by following the instructions from an online course (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#8) given by the android developer page in using Android Studio with Java.

After I add the lines to the project gradle file:
def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

and to the app gradle file:
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

My project is failed to synchronize with the Gradle files. Could someone solve the error and explain this error to me? I have tried to rebuild the project, but it didn't work out.
Below is the code and the error:

Error:
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @42d80b78)
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @42d80b78)

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P2lA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sAND.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Vvg.png)

Comment: Try replacing `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` with `id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below lines As It's working fine for me.

```
 // Add to Porject level gralde file
 def nav_version = "2.3.5"
 classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

 //Add to Module level gralde file.
 id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

Difference b/w androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin and androidx.navigation.safeargs

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' is for Java/Kotlin mixed modules

id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' is for pure Kotlin modules.
```

Plus put the plugin at the end e-g check below example

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Other Info, You can try below options as well.

```
-Check If the Gradle is on online mode not offline (Right side menu bar click on Gradle =//= check If that sign is not pressed.)
-Clean your project then rebuild
-Invalidate Cache and Restart
```

Comment: I have tried the method above and modified the code a bit but I am not sure I placed the code correctly, especially the part of "apply plugin". I placed it within the plugins. The instructions are not clear, as the code doesn't look as expected.

Comment: Please check the answer again I have modified the code. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Oh, I meant the instructions from the course. Anyway, It works now. Thanks so much!